# elasticsearch query for finding id in fields in json file

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a json file that I indexed on elasticsearch and I need a query to retrieve "_id_osm". can you help me plz.
and this is one line of my json file:

```
{
  "index": {
    "_index": "pariss",
    "_type": "sig",
    "_id": 1
  }
}{
  "fields": {
    "_id_osm": 416747747,
    "_categorie": "",
    "_name": [
      ""
    ],
    "_location": [
      36.1941834,
      5.3595221
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments in the answer updated the answer,

**If you have `store` true in your mapping for `_id_osm` then you can use below query to fetch the field value.**

```
{
  "stored_fields" : ["_id_osm"],
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Above call returns below response and you can notice the `fields` section in the response which contains the field name and value.

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "intqu",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "fields": {
                    "_id_osm": [
                        416747747
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

If you don't have `store` true which is default, then use `_source` filtering to get the data.

```
{
  "_source": [ "_id_osm" ],
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  }
}
```

which returns below response, you can see `_source` has the data.

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "intqu",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "_id_osm": 416747747
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: i work with a big json and yes i want to get the field value from _id_osm. with this request I can retrieve the value of id:                                                                         request_body = '''
            {
               "query": {
                 "match": {"_id": "'''+_id+'''"}
               }
            }
            '''                                                                                                                 but now I need an elasticsearch request which gives me the value of _id_osm

Comment: @NargesRastgoyan which version of elasticsearch you are using

Comment: elasticsearch-5.6.3

Comment: @NargesRastgoyan any luck?